# backing up restricted folder

Tags: backup, mount, fsck

my MacBook just died and I have really important data on my `Macintosh HD`. So I try to do a backup using Ubuntu 12.10 (Windows does not recognize the Volume as it is `HFS+ Journaled`, may also be a Win8 bug)
I can access the volume but I can't access my users folder, as the volume is read-only, and rwx is revoked for groups and others ...

```
paul@ubuntu:/dev$ sudo fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sda2
** /dev/sda2
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking multi-linked files.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Checking Extended Attributes file.
** Checking volume bitmap.
** Checking volume information.
** The volume Macintosh HD appears to be OK.
```

Any ideas (sorry if this is very easy, I am new to UNIX shells)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be root to do this, not just superuser.

Comment: How can I do that? I know the user account & pw from my mac and I know all the logins for Ubuntu. Can you give me an example please?